# Handle exception in for comprehension

Tags: scala, exception

How should I handle potential exceptions in for comprehensions?  In this example, I want to handle a `MatchException` that occurs when the line isn't properly formatted.  I would like to throw a more informative exception that includes the line string.  The problem is the the line string is only known *inside* the for comprehension, but traditional error handling with `try/catch` would be *outside* the for comprehension.

```
    val gold = Resource.using (Source.fromFile(file)) { source =>
      (for {
        line <- source.getLines
        Array(annotation, string, _ @ _*) = line.split("\t")
        boolean = if (annotation == "1") true else false
      } yield {
        string -> boolean
      }).toMap
    }
```

Scala 2.10's `Try` might be helpful here, but I'm still on 2.9.2.

Comment: Looks like [Try was backported to 2.9.3](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/index.html#scala.util.Try) as well, as Futures and Promises, thus you can easily migrate to 2.9.3 (which is binary compatible with 2.9.1/2, just swap artifacts) and enjoy it

Comment: Cool, I'm still not sure how I'd use it exactly to get the line text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is update your exception to be more detailed, you can:

```
for {
  line <- List("salmon\tcod", "wooble")
  (annotation, string) = try { 
    val Array(a, s, _ @ _*) = line.split("\t"); (a, s)
  } catch {
    case me: MatchError => throw new MatchError("Line '"+line+"' not in proper form")
  }
  boolean = (annotation=="1")
} yield (string -> boolean)
```

That is, do the parsing and return what you want inside a `try` block.  `Try` is only slightly helpful here; I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

Seems simpler to use the match operator

```
line.split("\t") match {
  case Array(a, s, _ @ _*) => (a, s)
  case _ => throw new MatchError("Line '"+line+"' not in proper form")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If as suggested by om-nom-nom you get Try, you can do something like this

```
Array( annotation, string, _@ _* ) = 
                Try( line.split( "\t" )).recover({ case e: Exception => Failure(new MyException("my message")) }).get
```

In short your *recover*, rewrap the Exception in what you want then unwrap the result or throw the new exception using `get`

If you cannot get hold of `Try` since `try...catch` is an expression in Scala and not a statement, you can write almost the same thing using it.

```
Array( annotation, string, _@ _* ) = 
try { line.split( "\t" )} catch { case e: Exception =>  throw new MyException("my message")}
```